# React-apollo update not reloading after mutation if I transform data before the render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-adopt

I have wrapped for both Query and Mutations so I can globally handle the repeat actions that need to happen with each `Query, Mutation`. In the query I transform the data so I don't need to worry about all the `nodes, edges, etc`

I am using [`react-adopt`](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt) to wrap all my `query` and `mutations` components into one render prop back on the view layer.

## Works - Page will re-render once a mutation has taken place

#### `<ApolloQuery>`

```
export const ApolloQuery = ({
  query: query,
  render,
}) => {
  return (
    <Query query={query}>
      {({ data }) => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
               render(data)
          </Fragment>
        )
      }}
    </Query>
  )
}
```

#### A Component

```
export default externalProps => {
  return (
    <QueryContainer {...externalProps}>
      {({ someQueryData, aMutation }) => { //react-adopt render props
        const { nestedData } = new apolloClass(someQueryData).start()
        return (
          <Grid container spacing={16}>
            {nestedData.map((ticket, index) => (
               {...Mutation button in here}
            ))}
         </Grid>
        )
      }}
    </QueryContainer>
  )
}
```

## Does not work - Page does not re-render but cache is updated with correct records

#### `<ApolloQuery>`

```
    <Query query={query}>
      {({ data }) => {
        const transformedData = new apolloClass(data).start() //move transform into render
        return (
          <Fragment>
               render(transformedData)
          </Fragment>
        )
      }}
    </Query>
```

#### A Component

```
export default externalProps => {
  return (
    <QueryContainer {...externalProps}>
      {({ someQueryData: { nestedData }, aMutation }) => {
        return (
          <Grid container spacing={16}>
            {nestedData.map((ticket, index) => (
               {...Mutation button in here}
            ))}
         </Grid>
        )
      }}
    </QueryContainer>
  )
}
```

So now, the page will not update after a mutation if I move the `apolloClass` to transform before the render of the `query`

Comment: can you please add a live example?  Also, what is the purpose of `react-adopt`? Why not try without it?

Comment: Interesting, ye I will try to put together a sandbox this evening. Adpot is simply so when we return the components, we don't have to nest many times. So ease of us, but yes, you are right we do not need to use this.

Comment: Using sandbox will be difficult as I'll need a running version of our graphql server and the service is a private one, behind a firewall.

Comment: Most likely this has something to do with React's shallow comparison when rendering.

Comment: Ye, I believe this should work as this is done on the ID, which do map up, at least... I believe they do :D

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to set `refetchQueries` or `awaitRefetchQueries` in the [mutation options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/) to force Apollo updating those queries and hence triggering a re-render.

Comment: Thanks SirPeople. I already have this working with refetch, but this is not at all what I want to do. With a simple mutation I was hoping the mapping would redraw for me without the need for the extra call.

Comment: Hmmm... Have you tried using dataIdFromObject in the InMemoryCache? Maybe that will trigger the refetch... But there is a reason for the refetch to exist here

Comment: I'll do some reading on `dataIdFromObject`. I would prefer to use `update` over `refetch` if i'm honest.

Comment: Can I ask why the solution with refetch is that bad? Just curious

Comment: Because our users have extremely limited data, which means fine turning all aspects of the app. 1 more quest for data is extremely bad for our users. If I can do them all in 1, then we can keep their loading times down drasticaly and more importantly them happy.

Comment: What about using the answer from the mutation to get the data that you need to update (in case is few values). Otherwise, maybe playing with fetch policies could do refetch as a look up in the cache data

Comment: Ye, using the update is the alternative. I have to say, for such a simple mutation whcih only returns 1 level deep, i would rather know how this works and not have to write a update for every single mutation that is root level query. If you understand me? I'd like to just know how/why I can get this working. if its a complex mutation and return data sure, but its just a id

Comment: There is some people that claim they can help you to not repeat yourself with the update everywhere (https://github.com/ecerroni/apollo-cache-updater, eventho for me it seems as annyoing as to declare update in every mutation). Probably there is no easier way as it is rright now, but I believe they were working on something rrelated in the Apollo Cache package

Comment: Ye, really I would not like to manage updates, however. In this one very specific case, its really asking why doesn't the ID get updated when I can see the cache is update. Appreciate the time though mate

Comment: Ha, I thought this was another question. So I think you have missed the point of the question :) The page does `redraw` correctly, so long as I don't alter the data coming back BEFORE passing to the view. If I edit the data inside my component everything is fine.